# Spark Structured Streaming with TriggerAvailableNow and Eventhubs

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I have been trying to write events from a delta table in databricks to eventhubs and I have been having issues with trying to make it work with Trigger availableNow=True,

I am basically collecting events which first reads the required delta table, add a watermark, do some transformations, create an event dataframe with some added metadata columns, convert it to a format to push into eventhubs,

The thing is it works when I set the processingTime trigger to 2 seconds but doesn't work with availableNow=True, I am not able to understand why this is so.

Can anyone provide a solution to make it work with availableNow or the reasons behind why it doesn't

Sample Code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import base64

def _get_connection_string() -> str:  # pragma: no cover
    """Provides connection string from the secret."""
    connection_string_secret = "MetaEventhubConnectionStringDevelopment"
    secret_scope = "mr-wallet"
    encoded_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope=secret_scope, key=connection_string_secret)
    
    return base64.b64decode(encoded_secret).decode()

def _transform_events_information(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    select_cols = ["EventTime", "Source", "Error"]
    date_interval = "14 days"
    window = f.window(f.col("EventTime"), windowDuration=date_interval)
    df_transformed = (df.withColumnRenamed("SourceLocator", "Source")
                        .withColumnRenamed("_commit_timestamp", "EventTime")
                        .withColumn("Error", f.lit(None))
                        .groupBy("Source", "Error", window).agg(f.min("EventTime").alias("EventTime"))
                        .select(*select_cols)
                        )

    return df_transformed


def _add_watermark(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    watermark_interval = "1 second"
    df = df.withWatermark("_commit_timestamp", watermark_interval)

    return df

def _read_source_table():  # pragma: no cover
    source_table = 'eventlog.common_source'
    df = spark.readStream.format("delta") \
        .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
        .table(source_table)

    return df

def collect() -> DataFrame:  # pragma: no cover
    """Prepares information on processed files."""
    df = _read_source_table()
    df = _add_watermark(df)
    df = _transform_events_information(df)

    return df

def _build_events(df: DataFrame, destination_table_path: str, data_product_name: str, workflow_name: str) -> DataFrame:
    output_columns = ["EventTime", "Application", "DataProduct", "Source", "Destination", "Error"]
    date_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    df = (df.withColumn("EventTime", f.date_format(f.col("EventTime"), date_format))
            .withColumn("Destination", f.lit(destination_table_path))
            .withColumn("DataProduct", f.lit(data_product_name))
            .withColumn("Application", f.lit(workflow_name))
            )
    return df.select(*output_columns)


def _push_events(df: DataFrame) -> None:  # pragma: no cover
    checkpoint_path = "/FileStore/asarkar/test_pushing_events/checkpoint"
    connection_string = _get_connection_string()
    eventhub_utils = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils
    write_options = {"eventhubs.connectionstring": eventhub_utils.encrypt(connection_string)}

    bootstrap_servers = "df-event-hub-weu-sprint.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
    eventhub_endpoint = _get_connection_string()


    # EH_SASL = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"Endpoint=sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=XXXXXX;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXX\";"
    EH_SASL = f"kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"{eventhub_endpoint}\";"

    topic = "meta"

    # (df.writeStream
    #     .format("kafka")
    #     .option("topic", topic)
    #     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers)
    #     .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
    #     .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
    #     .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL)
    #     .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
    #     # .trigger(processingTime='2 seconds')
    #     .start())

    (df.writeStream
        .format("eventhubs")
        .options(**write_options)
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
        .trigger(availableNow=True)
        .start()
        # .awaitTermination()
        )
 
def _prepare_events(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    output_df = (
        df.select(
            f.to_json(f.create_map(
                f.lit('EventTime'), f.col('EventTime'),
                f.lit('Application'), f.col('Application'),
                f.lit('DataProduct'), f.col('DataProduct'),
                f.lit('Source'), f.col('Source'),
                f.lit('Destination'), f.col('Destination'),
                f.lit('Error'), f.col('Error')
            )).alias('body')
        )
        # .select(f.to_json(f.struct("body")).alias("value"))
    )
    return output_df
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Available Now and Processing Time triggers have very different semantics, so it's hard to know what you mean by "doesn't work." To recap:

- Available Now will process only the data that is available at the beginning at the start of the Structured Streaming job. If no new data is available, the stream will *exit completely*.
- Processing Time trigger with your parameter of 2 seconds will start a batch at most every 2 seconds. If there's no data available at second 0, it will check to see if there's more data (and execute a batch, if so) at second 2.

So, if you start a query with Available Now and notice that no data arrives in EventHubs, it's very likely because no new data is available; it likely works with the Processing Time (of 2 seconds) trigger since the job keeps polling for new data and *eventually* finds and processes that new data.

You can verify what's actually being processed for a particular trigger by looking at the `numInputRows` metric of the streaming query progress, which will get printed to the *driver logs*, which you can find in the Spark UI (note: this log is not in the output of a Databricks notebook cell).

Comment: I think its my bad, I didn't give proper context,
How would you do it for stateful streaming because at the moment we have a stateful stream (because of group by with min() aggregation) and we are unable to push such dataframe with AvailableNow using streamWrite and eventhubs format

Comment: Triggers affect both stateless and stateful streams in the same way. I don't know what you mean by "unable to push such dataframe with AvailableNow." Can you clarify?

Comment: I added some sample code, maybe that might help further

Comment: None of these functions even seem to be called, so I still don't quite know what you mean by "unable to push such dataframe with AvailableNow." If you come up with a minimal reproduction (or just describe what's not working), I'll be able to be much more helpful.